# Connection refused when accessing web app through Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-machine

I'm pretty new to Docker, so I'm trying to take a node web app that I've written and Docker-ize it.  The app is open source, so you can find it and the Dockerfile here: [Paw-Wars](https://github.com/snollygolly/paw-wars/tree/docker)

So you don't have to click through, the Dockerfile is here:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node

WORKDIR /src
ADD . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE  5050
COPY config.json /src/config.json
CMD npm run docker
```

So I open up the Docker Quickstart Terminal (I'm on Mac OS X), go to my path, and build it:

```
docker build -t paw-wars .
```

After it builds, I run it:

```
docker run paw-wars
```

And it spins up just fine and says it's listening on port 5050.  I get the ip from `docker-machine ip default`, and try to connect to it on port 5050, but I get connection refused.  Most searches I've done trying to solve this tell me that I need to make sure to use the correct IP, but I'm almost positive I'm doing that.  Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.  It's not in the repo, but I've also tried binding to `0.0.0.0` in my app (index.js), but that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you MUST specify a port in your `docker run` command.  I thought that using `EXPOSE` in your dockerfile is sufficient, but it's not.  That's just to get the port exposed internally.

`docker run -p 5050:5050 paw-wars` worked great.

Comment: or use the `host` network: `docker run --net=host paw-wars`, or use the [`-P` `docker run` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) and the [`docker port`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/) command

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Thomasleveil!

Comment: Likewise, if you are doing `docker-compose run paw-wars` you will also need to specify the port on the command line, oddly, but if this is the case, just go the full docker-compose way and specify the ports in the docker-compose.yml file and do `docker-compose up -d`